# Printing a letter for 5 times with jumps in Assembly x86, infinite loop

Tags: assembly, x86

Well, I understood how to do a jump for a defined number of times (like, 5 times), but I have some problems when I try to print a char: the program goes in a loop.
This is what I managed to do at this time...
(everything below is the code)

```
section .data
    letter db 65 ;A in ASCII
    cont dw 5 ;The number of times it should print the letter

section .bss

section .text

global _start

_start:
    ;This is the printing of the letter
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, letter
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80    

     ;And this is where I got stuck, it goes in a loop and I don't know how to fix this
    mov ecx, [cont]  
    dec ecx
    jnz _start

_fine: ;it ends the program
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

Comment: I don't understand... You put a loop but you don't want a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation what is happening:

```
    mov ecx, [cont]
; you did load 32b value from memory into ecx
; lower 16bits are 5 (from "dw 5"), upper 16b undefined (probably 0 by luck)
    dec ecx
; you decrement ecx to (4 + undefined upper 16b) (value in memory intact)
    jnz _start
; and jump to _start
```

During second iteration the same thing happens. Actually the very **same**. Including the value in memory being still equal to 5 + something.

You can either keep the counter all the time in some register, so initialize it once **ahead** of loop (like `mov ecx,5` and then preserve `ecx` value during loop).

Or if you want to keep it in memory, the `dec` can work with memory in this case too:

```
    dec WORD [cont]
; decrement only 16bit data, because "dw" was used to define word.
; in first iteration memory content would become 4 from 5
    jnz _start
```

Or another way to fix such issue is to store updated value from register into memory:

```
    mov cx, [cont]   ; also fixed to 16b only to respect "dw"
    dec cx
    mov [cont], cx   ; write new value back into memory
    jnz _start
```

---

BTW, this should be **obviously** visible in **debugger**. So you either didn't even try, or you don't understand the debugger - how it displays values of registers and how you can check content of memory.

In either case, invest several days into learning how to work with debugger, as programming in Assembly without debugger is like building a robot blindfolded (you don't want to, really).

Comment: @CarbonaraSlayer: Any of the suggestions works. If you just copy the working line for you and you don't pay attention to rest of it, you are narrowing your own knowledge, which will limit you in future, and it will keep pushing you toward weird inefficient solutions. The more insight you gain, and the more variants of possible solutions you know, the easier it will be to do things in Assembly for you. Up to certain expertise level. From there you will know too much, actually complicating things, as you will be reluctant to use simple-but-slow instructions, etc.. But you are far away from that.

Comment: @Ped7g Well, thank you for the time you gave to my question. And yes, I probably didn't even try with my forces to understand the assembly ;______;